# which C++ Compiler complies with the latest C++ standard most

Tags: c++, compiler-construction

I have been looking for a c++ compiler that is available and complies most with the latest C++ standard.

The latest VS2010 is good but as many said it still doesn't comply with all of the C++ standard.

Comment: Has C++0x been formally ratified yet?  I was under the impression there was just a draft at this point.

Comment: @templatetypedef:  [It is being voted on.](http://twitter.com/#!/sdt_intel/status/100618449545461760)

Comment: It is still not formally approved, but we all know what it will look like (unless the committee members who unanimously approved the FDIS can convince their respective national bodies to reject the proposal). You'll get a  better odds on "Elvis lives".

Comment: @Bo wow, it's that close to being rejected?

Comment: @Seth you need to use at least 3 chars after at-sign to have the desired effect

Comment: @relaxxx - No, it works anyway. There was a fix for us poor guys who only have 2 characters in our first name. :-)

Comment: @Bo oh, didn't know that, [this](http://stackoverflow.com/editing-help#comment-formatting) says 3 is min and I read it this morning :)

Comment: @relaxxx - If the third character is a space it will work somehow anyway. Noticed a post on meta that it was considered in the matching.

Comment: @Seth - Still wanna place a bet? [http://herbsutter.com/2011/08/12/we-have-an-international-standard-c0x-is-unanimously-approved/](http://herbsutter.com/2011/08/12/we-have-an-international-standard-c0x-is-unanimously-approved/)

Comment: @Bo awesome! It's about time.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

you may be interested in  [this](http://wiki.apache.org/stdcxx/C++0xCompilerSupport) summary table

EDIT:

I have found the [list](http://www.aristeia.com/C++11/C++11FeatureAvailability.htm) of tables created by Scott Meyers

Comment: @Seth : Actually, Clang rocks; that chart isn't up to date. :-]

Answer (score 1):

GCC has pretty good C++0x compliance, [here is a list](http://gcc.gnu.org/projects/cxx0x.html) of the features it supports

Answer (score 0):

GCC and Clang are very good ones. Visual Studio (of any year) will require special cases for complex code so it doesn't really comply with standards.

Comment: Prejudiced much? Maybe if you'd taken a minute to read the other answers you would've spotted [this](https://wiki.apache.org/stdcxx/C++0xCompilerSupport) table. If you don't count GCC, MSVC 10 is as good as or better than other mainstream compilers out there.

Comment: @Praetorian - Right now the latest release of any compiler is the most compliant. Version 2010 is obviously at a disadvantage compared to those who managed to have a 2011 release.

Comment: @Bo Persson Yes, of course, I don't disagree. I'd imagine GCC has the shortest release cycle of all the compilers in that table, consequently it has implemented the most C++0x features. But saying a compiler, which was released prior to the existence of the standard, is non-compliant, is naive.

Comment: @Praetorian : Also, VC++ 2010 was based on N3000, while the FDIS is N3290. Consequently, many of the C++0x features it does implement are not conformant to the FDIS' wording, causing incompatibilities between C++0x code for VC++ vs. C++0x code for other compilers (that do target the FDIS). VC6 was in the same situation, and there's no shortage of people willing to say VC6 is 'non-compliant'.